# Is it against the HIG for a UITableViewCell to remain Highlighted?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, app-store

Is it against the HIG for a UITableViewCell to remain Highlighted? Currently, when a cell is selected it just remains blue. I am unsure if I need to add:

```
NSIndexPath *tableSelection = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:tableSelection animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HIG says

> Appearance and Behavior
>
> A table view displays data in rows
>   that can be divided by section or
>   separated into groups. Users flick or
>   drag to scroll through rows or groups
>   of rows. Users tap a table row to
>   select it and use table view controls
>   to add or remove rows, select multiple
>   rows, see more information about a row
>   item, or reveal another table view. A
>   table row highlights briefly when the
>   user taps a selectable item.
>
> If a row selection results in
>   navigation to a new screen, the
>   selected row highlights briefly as the
>   new screen slides into place. When the
>   user navigates back to the previous
>   screen, the originally selected row
>   again highlights briefly to remind the
>   user of their earlier selection (it
>   does not remain highlighted).
>
> Always provide feedback when users
>   select a list item. Users expect a
>   table row to highlight briefly when
>   they tap a selectable item in it.
>   After tapping, users expect an
>   immediate action to occur: Either a
>   new view appears or the row displays a
>   checkmark to indicate that the item
>   has been selected or enabled.
>
> **In rare cases, a row might remain
>   highlighted when secondary details or
>   controls related to the row item are
>   displayed in the same screen. However,
>   this is not encouraged because it is
>   difficult to display simultaneously a
>   list of choices, a selected item, and
>   related details or controls without
>   creating an uncomfortably crowded
>   layout.**